# Show parks in terrain view

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use a map with the "terrain"-view on. But in this view the POI -> Parks are somehow overlayed. Any idea how to solve this? Maybe overlaying an terrain-map with an standard roadmap?

Funny thing is: when zoom level >13, the Parks are shown, maybe this zoom level can be adjusted?

I don't know how but somehow http://instaearth.me/ solved this problem.

Comment: There is nothing special with the linked  map. Some POIs will be seen at lower zoom-levels, some at higher zoom-levels. It mostly will depend on the prominence and area of a park. When you want to set a minimum zoom-level use the `minZoom` of the map.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to see your tweet.  I don't remember doing anything special when we did instaearth.  Our zoom level is very high so we're right down on top of the map when you zoom in.  I think @Dr.Molle has the right answer here.  The higher you zoom up the less detail you'll have.